# .site-content is larger than #main.wrapper (it's container)

Tags: html, css

I am not an expert in this, but I have managed to build a website or two and have a reasonable grasp of css.

All the other pages on the website respond properly to a browser resize but on this page and only this page; http://theayurvedapractice.com/category/blog/ there is a problem.

It happens when the browser is reduced from full width.

The .site-content usually resizes when the #main.wrapper reduces in size but on this page, it remains bigger and therefore the contents stay bigger than the browser.

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm sure it's something simple (I hope!).

Thanks,
Kate

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies in this rule.

```
    #page {
        background: white url(images/torn_paper_edge.jpg) top left repeat-x;  
        min-width: 800px;
       }
```

sets minimum width of 800px to blog pages.
found in child theme style.css
hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Dan for your help.  I took this css away and it doesn't fix the problem so I guess it isn't that?  Any other ideas to try? I have been wracking my brain for days!

Comment: Sorry took a good look over everything that I have access to in the browser. Can't find any definitive answer. noticed you relocated sidebar to the left (twenty twelve was right). I would check those mods first.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it so thoroughly Dan, I appreciate it.